# Which maps from R (with its usual metric) to a discrete metric space are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Which maps from the real numbers (with its usual metric) to a discrete metric space are continuous?

I stumbled across an answer I don't quite understand:

If $$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow   X$$ is continuous and X is discrete, this means that the inverse image of every singleton set is open. But then we cannot have any interval $(a, b)$ which is mapped to more than one point. Hence the only continuous functions are constant ones.

The part that "(...)But then we cannot have any interval $(a, b)$ which is mapped to more than one point." I don't quite follow. This might be clear as day, but I feel maybe a comment or two more would make all the difference (to me).

Comment: If $f$ has inverse in $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ sense then it's bijective and therefore it's injective, i.e. all mappings must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the intended implication is that if an interval is mapped to more than one point then you can express that interval as a disjoint union of open sets, which is impossible because the interval is connected. However, I don't understand why you can't just apply that argument directly to $\mathbb R$.